# iOS-Charts draw 2 chart views with same YAxis

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I'm implementing a line chart on iOS with ability for comparing data using [iOS Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) and Swift

#### Simplest Scenario

Compare data of Jan 04 to Jan 05, Jan 05 to Jan 06, Jan 06 to Jan 07 and so on...

So, I need to draw 2 lines with **different XAxis** (second line is 1 day shifted of first line) and same YAxis

#### I did

Create 2 line chart views (`LineChartView`), 1 with top XAxis and legend ; and 1 with bottom XAxis and legend

#### Problems

1. Because of space of XAxis labels and legends, 2 lines has different YAxis position (e.g: 0 value of line 1 is around 96 value of line 2). I think some margin may resolve this problem but I can find only 1 option `minOffset`, which set margins for all top, bottom, left and right. What thing I can use to only margin top and bottom?
2. All interactions (drag, zoom, touch, etc) only affect 1 of them, not both. How can I make interactions applied to both of them?

**Update**
I resolved first issue by adding minTopBottomOffset and modifying `ChartViewBase` to use it

More information about what I'm expecting:

- I have a data like this: `[{time: Jan 01, value: 10}, {time: Jan 02, value: 13}, {time: Jan 03, value: 5}]`
- `time` is X, `value` is Y
- I want to draw first line with XAxis at bottom, second line with XAxis displayed on top and second line has XAxis shifted to the right 1 day. 2 lines have same data

See my expected chart here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DT3STrB2t3UW0wTXpKU1RHSTA/view

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show the code of how you're setting it up?

Comment: @AdityaGarg I only created 2 `LineChartView` inside same UIView and draw them. 1 with top XAxis and legend ; and 1 with bottom XAxis and legend. No special configurations

Comment: I dont think Im quite following. If you are comparing 2 days, wouldnt they both have the same x and y axis? Thats the only way the comparison makes sense. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "day shifted"

Comment: @AdityaGarg Thanks for replying. I have same YAxis but not XAxis. My example:

- I have a data like this: `[{time: Jan 01, value: 10}, {time: Jan 02, value: 13}, {time: Jan 03, value: 5}]`
- `time` is X, `value` is Y
- I want to draw first line with XAxis at bottom, second line with XAxis displayed on top and second line has XAxis shifted to the right 1 day. 2 lines have **same data**

See my expected chart here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DT3STrB2t3UW0wTXpKU1RHSTA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

OK,I think your graph is as strange as mine. :p

1,What thing I can use to only margin top and bottom?

You need not add minTopBottomOffset to the BarLineChartViewBase.You should just use `setViewPortOffsets` method.

```
chartView.setViewPortOffsets(left: left, top: top, right: right, bottom: bottom)
```

2,All interactions (drag, zoom, touch, etc) only affect 1 of them, not both. How can I make interactions applied to both of them?

We can just do it in a little dirty way -- Add a block view to receive all gestures ,and pass them to each chart.

First, in `BarLineChartViewBase` ,add a method as below(The code is uncompleted.It only works for TapGestureRecognizer and PanGestureRecognizer now.).

```
//Modify
@objc open func receiveGestureRecognized(_ recognizer: NSUIGestureRecognizer)
{
    if recognizer is NSUITapGestureRecognizer
    {
        self.tapGestureRecognized(recognizer as! NSUITapGestureRecognizer)
    }
    else if recognizer is NSUIPanGestureRecognizer
    {
        self.panGestureRecognized(recognizer as! NSUIPanGestureRecognizer)
    }
}
```

Secondly ,you should add a block view in front of your two charts and cover them all.

Then add some code like these(example for PanGestureRecognizer):

```
 UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
[self.blockView addGestureRecognizer:panGestureRecognizer];
```

handleGesture:

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
[self.chartView1 receiveGestureRecognized:gestureRecognizer];
[self.chartView2 receiveGestureRecognized:gestureRecognizer];
}
```

So finally you can drag them at the same time.

Comment: Thank you, Y.Bi. I will try your solution when I have time (currently, my client accepted limitation of interacting with second chart)